# How can I avoid "Enabling Less Secure Apps Access" in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, phpmailer, outbound

I am trying to use Gmail outbound email settings so that I can send emails. My site has an active **SSL and working HTTPS** and also have the commonly required security extensions installed and enabled. I am using **PHPMailer**. But still I need to Enable "Less secure app access".
Is there anyway to avoid Enabling "Less secure app access" ???

```
    $phpMailerObj= new PHPMailer();

    $phpMailerObj->isSMTP();
    $phpMailerObj->SMTPAuth = true;
    $phpMailerObj->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $phpMailerObj->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $phpMailerObj->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com';
    $phpMailerObj->Port = 587;
    $phpMailerObj->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $phpMailerObj->SMTPAuth = true;
    $phpMailerObj->AuthType = 'LOGIN';
    $phpMailerObj->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $phpMailerObj->Password = "test_password";
    $phpMailerObj->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com', 'THE NAME OF THE SENDER',0);
    $phpMailerObj->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com', 'RECEIVER NAME');

    $phpMailerObj->Subject = 'SUBJECT';
    $phpMailerObj->Body ='MESSAGE';

    if (!$phpMailerObj->send()) {
        echo "phpMailerObjer Error: " . $phpMailerObj->ErrorInfo;
        return 0;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: YOu might want to check this [Using Gmail with XOAUTH2](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2)

Comment: @DaImTo I have added the code but this is not it as I have done a lot of edits to this one and revert it back to standard as on PHPMailer

Comment: actually I am getting settings from customers so thats more hectic for common users

Comment: Well tough luck. If you want to not enable less secure apps, you *have* to use XOAUTH2; there is no alternative. Yes, using OAuth for *anything* is deeply unpleasant, inconvenient, and difficult to manage, but you have no choice, so you need to deal with it. PHPMailer is the last link in the chain hore – you need to implement the equivalent of PHPMailer's `get_oauth_token.php` script in your own app if you're going to make it easy for users.

Comment: @devZ what settings are you getting from your customers?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. You can do it using `XOAUTH2.`

[Link to Wiki](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2)

[Sample Code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail_xoauth.phps)

And `get_oauth_token.php` explained in wiki is present in `PHPMailer/get_oauth_token.php`.

Comment: actually I am getting settings from customers so thats more hectic for common users

Comment: While I get that this is essentially a "links only" answer, it's also absolutely correct, so I'm not sure the downvotes are warranted.